# The trial period for this product has expired

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, farm, licence

I recently got my hands on a SharePoint 2007 single server farm. The exact version number is 12.0.0.6545. This farm has been running for many years.

The **Convert License Type** page says **Office SharePoint Server Trial with Enterprise Client Access License**

Is the license actually expired? I am able to do all sorts of things on this farm but there are some functions which when I perform give error **The trial period for this product has expired** so I am not really sure if it is expired or not.

For e.g. if I try to create a new site or site collection with template "Publishing Site" then I get this error. All other templates work fine for e.g. Team Site, Document Workspace etc.
Similarly if I try to add a workflow to a list or library then I get this error.

My farm account is part of local admin group and all application pools are running using this account. Similarly, SharePoint timer job is running with this account. I have done **iisreset** several times but no luck.

The only thing remaining to do is to run SharePoint Configuration Wizard but I dread to run it lest it breaks something.

How do I fix this issue? Is SharePoint Configuration Wizard the only solution?

Comment: `"How do I fix this issue?"` Buying a license seems like a good start.

Comment: Could be a bug as I found this but I will confirm it from customer tomorrow. https://support.microsoft.com/kb/971620. By the way if the license has really expired then shouldn't SharePoint cease to work? Or this is normal behavior that after license expiring, some functions work and some don't?

Comment: I don't know about SharePoint specifically, but this is typical Microsoft - if you install some versions of Windows and don't activate, or if it is a pirate copy, you will be able to use it, but lose some functions. For example, the wallpaper will always be black, you don't get non-security updates etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the license was actually expired. After expiration of license MOSS was working in Foundation mode. I applied license and now all features are working fine.